# "We can't sign into your account" is shown after restart on terminal server 2016

Tags: terminal-server, windows-server-2016, user-profile, user-profile-disks

We installed a complete new **server 2016 environment** with 5 **terminal servers** in a farm. We also use **User Profile Disks** for the profiles.

**The fault**:
When the domain administrator is logged on to any terminal server and the terminal server gets started, we get after the logon of the domain administrator this message:

> We can't sign into your account

... and the administrator gets a temporarily profile.

[image]

**After logoff / logon** the message isn't shown and the regular profile is loaded.

- We use the **console** logon for the rdp connection
- There is only one administrator logged on at one time
- The eventlog doesn't show any conspicuity.

---

**Edit#1**
From a comment: A similar error is described here: [technet group](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/89c19f15-4db0-4d86-8409-e3c86a26ce9d/we-cant-sign-into-your-account?forum=winserverTS). The cause in this case are DVDROM drives, which are connected to the location 1 on on the scsi-controller.

In my case the DVDROM drives are connected to SATA. For testing I removed the drives but the error still behaves.

**BUT: This may be an hint, that also in my case the user profile disks couldn't be properly connected.**

Comment: Have you seen this?: https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/89c19f15-4db0-4d86-8409-e3c86a26ce9d/we-cant-sign-into-your-account?forum=winserverTS

Comment: @batistuta09 didn't help. See the the edit#1 above.